# Using Matchers for Objects

Tags: selenium, junit, matcher

So I am trying to create a "TestClass" that basically holds onto my Matcher, actual results, error message, and test label.

However, I am slowly starting to realize this might not be possible but I feel like it should be.

Perhaps someone here can help.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public void runTest(){
        Assert.assertThat(testLabel + " " + errorMessage, actualResult, testToRun);
    }
```

or, since I am doing Selenium Tests, something like this:

```
public void runTestAsWebElement(String attributeToCheck){
        Object tempActualResult;

        switch (attributeToCheck.toLowerCase()){
            case "isdisplayed()":
            case "isdisplayed":
                tempActualResult = ((WebElement) actualResult).isDisplayed();
                break;
            case "isselected":
            case "isselected()":
                tempActualResult = ((WebElement) actualResult).isSelected();
                break;
            case "isenabled":
            case "isenabled()":
                tempActualResult = ((WebElement) actualResult).isEnabled();
                break;
            case "text":
                tempActualResult = ((WebElement) actualResult).getText();
                break;
            default:
                tempActualResult = ((WebElement) actualResult).getAttribute(attributeToCheck);
        }

        Assert.assertThat(testLabel + " " + errorMessage, tempActualResult, testToRun);
    }
```

However, I am wondering, will the matchers be able to figure out that the Actual Result is a String or Boolean? Or will it always fail since both objects are being compared as Objects, rather than strings (not sure how the underlying code would be executed).

Any advice on how to properly handle this situation would be much appreciated!

Just to give some context - I am currently writing code like this:

```
Switch(whatToTest){
  case "eye portfolio tests":
    customCheckErrorMessages.add("The Eye Portfolio header doesn't match expected user's value");
    customCheckActualResults.add(eyePortfolioPage.eyePortfolioAccountHeader);
    customCheckExpectedResults.add(holder);
    customCheckTests.add(containsString(holder));
    customTestAttributeToTest.add("text");
    break;
    //just showing what my step looks like
  }

String actualResult = "";
        for(int x = 0; x < customCheckErrorMessages.size(); x++){
            try{
                switch (customTestAttributeToTest.get(x)){
                    case "text":
                        actualResult = customCheckActualResults.get(x).getText();
                        break;
                    default:
                        actualResult = customCheckActualResults.get(x).getAttribute(customTestAttributeToTest.get(x));
                        break;
                }
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                //Assuming this field wasn't actually entered. Defaulting to getText
                actualResult = customCheckActualResults.get(x).getText();
            }

            System.out.println("Additional Test #" + (x+1));

            Assert.assertThat(customCheckErrorMessages.get(x) + " Expected: \"" + customCheckExpectedResults.get(x)
                    + "\", Actual: \"" + customCheckActualResults.get(x).getText().trim(),
                    actualResult.trim(),
                    customCheckTests.get(x));
        }
```

I would like to write code like this:

```
switch(whatIWantToTest){
  case "transaction tests":
    customTests.add(new TestClass("There should be at least one transaction appearing on the page", //error Message
                        "Looking For Transactions:", //Test Label
                        myOrdersPage.transactions.size(), //Actual Result
                        greaterThanOrEqualTo(1))); //Test to run (should contain expected result)
//Just showing what my step looks like
}

for (TestClass test : customTests){
            test.runTest();
        }
```

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to do.  Why are you putting a wrapper around simple tests?  If you really want to create a method to run asserts, make 1 method for each type of assertion (1 method to assert that it is displayed, 1 method to assert it has text containing X), and so forth.  All I see here is an excess layer of code.

Comment: @MrTi - I am doing this so my Cucumber Step functions can run all my tests in quick succession. Its mostly so my test code is easier to read

Comment: Updated Question for you

Comment: You are right MrTi, I way over thought this lol. I basically just encapsulated all my checks into a class which handled it for me :)

Comment: Hey, that's not uncommon for me either.  I do have an improvement for the code before, namely *don't* go from string to function call.  It requires the user to know stuff about the code that isn't easy to figure out.  Calling `testElementDisplayed(element)` is much more clear than calling `test("displayed", element)`.  A multitude of functions is not a bad thing.  (You can have the functions call other functions so you don't copy/paste code)

Comment: I agree that test("displayed", element) isn't as easy to read as testElementDisplayed(element), but then I can't use my for loop at the end since I won't know what test to run. I can make another 2 constructors though, one to take in a string and one to take in a boolean so its easier to write. This way you can pass in test(element.isDisplayed(), equalTo(expectedResult)); or with the text

Comment: Just realized that passing in the attribute to test is better since it will grab the value to test on test execution time rather than before hand, which might have issues associated with it :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I decided to use. If anyone has a better suggestion I would love to hear it :)

```
private String testType;
public String errorMessage,  testAttribute;
public WebElement actualResult;
public List<WebElement> actualResults;
public String providedStringValue = null;
public Boolean providedBooleanValue = null;
public Matcher testToRun;
public int attempts = 1;

//Empty Constructor
public TestCase() {
    errorMessage = "";
    testType = "";
    actualResult = null;
    actualResults = null;
    testToRun = null;
    providedStringValue = null;
    providedBooleanValue = null;
}

//Run Test as a String check
public TestCase(String errorMessage, String providedResult, Matcher testToRun){
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    providedStringValue = providedResult;
    testType = "String";
    this.testToRun = testToRun;
}

//Run Test as a Boolean check
public TestCase(String errorMessage, Boolean providedResult, Matcher testToRun){
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    providedBooleanValue = providedResult;
    testType = "Boolean";
    this.testToRun = testToRun;
}

//Run Test on a WebElement
public TestCase(String errorMessage, String testAttribute, WebElement actualResult, Matcher testToRun) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    testType = "WebElement";
    this.testAttribute = testAttribute;
    this.actualResult = actualResult;
    this.testToRun = testToRun;
}

//Run Test on a List<WebElement>
public TestCase(String errorMessage, String testAttribute, List<WebElement> actualResults, Matcher testToRun) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    testType = "List";
    this.testAttribute = testAttribute;
    this.actualResults = actualResults;
    this.testToRun = testToRun;
}

public void clearTest() {
    errorMessage = "";
    testType = "";
    testAttribute = "";
    actualResult = null;
    actualResults = null;
    testToRun = null;
    providedStringValue = null;
    providedBooleanValue = null;
}

public void runTest() {
    try {
        if (testType.equalsIgnoreCase("WebElement")) {
            runTestAsWebElement(testAttribute);
        } else if (testType.equalsIgnoreCase("List")) {
            runTestAsList(testAttribute);
        } else if(testType.equalsIgnoreCase("Boolean")){
            runTestAsBooleanCheck();
        } else if(testType.equalsIgnoreCase("String")){
            runTestAsStringCheck();
        } else {
            Assert.fail("Don't know how to run this test type");
        }
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        if (attempts < 5) {
            System.out.println("StaleElementReferenceException - Running test again");
            attempts++;
            runTest();
            return;
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    attempts = 1;
}

private void runTestAsStringCheck(){
    Assert.assertThat(errorMessage, providedStringValue, testToRun);
}

private void runTestAsBooleanCheck(){
    Assert.assertThat(errorMessage, providedBooleanValue, testToRun);
}

//Sometimes the actualResult is a WebElement which means the value to check is wrapped within another value.
private void runTestAsWebElement(String attributeToCheck) {
    Object actualResultHolder;

    switch (attributeToCheck.toLowerCase()) {
        case "exists":
        case "present":
            try{
                actualResult.isDisplayed(); //Forcing WebElement to look for element. If throws exception, element not found
                actualResultHolder = true;
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                actualResultHolder = false;
            }
            break;
        case"display":
        case "displayed":
        case "isdisplayed()":
        case "isdisplayed":
            try{
                actualResultHolder = actualResult.isDisplayed();
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
                System.out.println("Element not found");
                throw e;
                //actualResultHolder = false;
            }
            break;
        case "selected":
        case "isselected":
        case "isselected()":
            actualResultHolder = actualResult.isSelected();
            break;
        case "enabled":
        case "isenabled":
        case "isenabled()":
            actualResultHolder = actualResult.isEnabled();
            break;
        case "text":
            actualResultHolder = actualResult.getText().trim();
            break;
        default:
            if (attributeToCheck.contains("css: ")) {//In case we want to test the css attribute instead of the HTML attribute
                attributeToCheck = attributeToCheck.split("css: ")[1];
                actualResultHolder = actualResult.getCssValue(attributeToCheck);
            } else {
                actualResultHolder = actualResult.getAttribute(attributeToCheck);
            }
    }

    Assert.assertThat(errorMessage + "\n Actual Result = \"" + actualResultHolder + "\" ", actualResultHolder, testToRun);
}

private void runTestAsList(String attributeToCheck) {
    switch (attributeToCheck.toLowerCase()) {
        case "size":
        case "size()":
            Assert.assertThat(errorMessage, actualResults.size(), testToRun);
            break;
        default:
            //do nothing - Test has to do with the list of elements.
            Assert.assertThat(errorMessage, actualResults, testToRun);
    }
}
```

Then, if for whatever reason I need some other type of test I just add it to the class.